# Is it possible to use one jquery in one specific part of my page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry if my question is too easy, I just trying to learn how to be my self clear, and as a novice I Find this most dificult.
Well, for exemple, I need to use:

```
<script src="/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
 my code (sortable funcions)
</script>
```

And that is ok for me! **but** once I add more **< scripts  xxxx.js>** my all page freezes...

my console returns:

```
form:699 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).minicolors is not a function
or
common-scripts.js?1455274914:87 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).niceScroll is not a function
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).sparkline is not a function
```

**So, here is my question:**

- 1) How to solve this conflicts? Are they conflicts?
- 2) Is it possible to run this "jquery-1.12.3.min.js" in one small part of may page? like:

  ```
  <script src="/minicolors.js"></script>
  <script src="/nicescroll.js"></script>

      <script src="/jquery-1.12.3.min.js">
             my JS code  (sortable funcions)
      </script>

  </script>
  ```

  the rest of JS code( minicolors and nicescroll)

  And by doing this, prevent erros?

Comment: Are you using [Chrome Dev Tools?](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools)  Are you seeing any errors for libraries failing to get loaded?

Comment: Could you give us the name of this `xxxx.js`? It might has a dependency on jQuery and is required to be loaded after you load jQuery.

Comment: Load jQuery first, then `minicolors.js` and `nicescroll.js`. Your own application code needs to be included last.

Comment: @ zipzit r: I just get "TypeError"....

Comment: @KuN <?php echo Asset::js(array('jquery.js', 'jquery.dcjqaccordion.2.7.js','jquery-ui.min.js','jquery.scrollTo.min.js','jquery.nicescroll.js','jquery.sparkline.js','jquery.pulsate.min.js','slidebars.min.js','bootstrap.min.js','autosize.min.js')); ?>
**AND** 
  /raphael-min.js"
/morris.min.js"
/jquery.noty.packaged.js
/DT_bootstrap.css
/bootstrap-datepicker.js
/bootstrap-datepicker.ja.js

   **AND my:** 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/jquery-sortable/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/jquery-sortable/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Comment: @Jeff i try to put it before... affter... but same errors....

Answer (score 2):

you need to take care of the order in which the files are loaded...

- Always load jquery library first, And then rest all plugin's can come through.

use this order

```
< script src="/jquery-1.12.3.min.js" ></script>   // 1st load jquery library
< script src="/minicolors.js" >< /script >        // other plugin after jquery
< script src="/nicescroll.js" >< /script >        // other plugins after jquery

< script type="text/javascript">                  //your custom code
           my JS code  (sortable funcions)
< / script>
```

Regarding the errors

```
form:699 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).minicolors is not a function
or
common-scripts.js?1455274914:87 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).niceScroll is not a function
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).sparkline is not a function
```

This happens because the jquery library is not loaded, So the plugins will also crash (As it is written in Jquery). If you change the order as mentioned everything should be fine

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
<script src="other_lib.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$.noConflict();
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
// Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
});
// Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
```

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to put your script-Code in the `$(document).ready(function(){})` body. This will prevent the executing of yur script before the site is loaded completely.

I assume that you want to execute some functions when you clicked on a button or some `<input>` or `<select>` has changed.

Therefore you can do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#'+yourButtonId).click(function(){
        //do what you want to do when your button was clciked
    });

    $('#'+yourInputOrSelectId).on('change',function(){
        //do whatever you want when the user typed sth in yout input or 
        //selected an item out of your <select>
        myCustomFunction('NewOption');
    });

    function myCustomFunction(argument){
       //do custom things with the argument
       //you can also do things with your elements on the web site
       $('#'+selecId).empty(); //just an example
       $('#'+selectId).append( $('<option/>').val(argument) );
    }
}
```